# launcher hangs ubuntu 14.10 in high resolution display

Tags: nvidia, launcher, display, resolution

Issue occurs when I click on launcher, display hangs and unable to recover session. Top bar graphics goes awol. This only happens when I using the highest resolution display (1920x1080), all of the other option display resolutions are okay. This occurs in both Ubuntu 14.04 and 14.10 OS.

Hardware platform is a Dell XPS M1330 with an NVIDA GeForce 8400M video card connected via VGA interface to a Dell S2440L monitor. I have to use the monitor due to the fact my XPS laptop display is not functioning correctly. No mirroring is used. Display is only viewed on Dell monitor.

Any suggestions for a solution would be appreciated.

Comment: What driver are you using? It might work better with the proprietary nvidia drivers. It might be best to make a bugreport about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a graphic card issue to me. To start off with, type "lspci | grep VGA" and take a note of your Graphic card model, just to make sure it is NVidia GeForce 8400M.

You are probably using the xorg open sourced driver right now and high resolution can create problems, as far as I'm aware.

To install the unofficial drivers, follow these steps :

Press Ctrl + Alt + F2 and login with your credentials. Now as root, run the following commands :

`killall -9 kdm` (KDE)

Or,

`killall -9 gdm(`Gnome)

Now, type :

`killall -9 Xorg`

And run the following commands :

`sudo apt-get --purge remove nvidia-current`

`sudo apt-get --purge autoremove`

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates`

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get -y install nvidia-current`

Comment: That appears to have solved my launcher/max def display issue. Although there are text messages which now appear in the logging off. Thank you for the input and solution.

Comment: What message are you getting?

Comment: It's very difficult to see, given the messages are on the laptop screen not Dell monitor. When I power it up, message roughly states:            uncvideo fails to initiate; uncvideo error; When I now login, screen looks okay, launcher appears to work, pull up a browser chrome or firefox just hangs the machine. Unable to do anything. This is a new feature, did not experience this after I made patches.